# Why is float's precision the same as double's?

Tags: c#, floating-point

Running this code yields the same precision numbers in both cases

```
double test = 0.5d;
while (1d != 1d + test) {
    Console.WriteLine(test);
    test /= 2d;
}
```

Last output line: 2,22044604925031E **-16**

```
float test2 = 0.5f;
while (1f != 1f + test2) {
    Console.WriteLine(test2);
    test2 /= 2f;
}
```

Last output line: 2,220446E **-16**

According the official MSDN docs ([float](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1e65aza.aspx) and [double](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/678hzkk9.aspx)) the output of the float test should have been something like 2,220446E **-7**. Do i have a conceptual misunderstanding or a programming error?

Comment: here precision is number of digits can be stored after most valuable digit. precision does not mean the precision of number it self

Answer (score 8):

Conceptual misunderstanding. Precision tends to show in the number of decimal points, the number after the E is the **exponent**, which tells you how big or small the number is. Notice how the float does indeed have many fewer decimal places than the double!